# Final variable inside a method with an inner class

Tags: java, variables, inner-classes, final

Let us look at the following code (Let `A` be some simple class in the same package):

```
public class MyClass {
    public void outer() {
        int i=3;
        int j=i++;   // 1
        A a = new A() {
            int k = i++;   // 2
        };
    }
}
```

While the line `1` compiles without a problem, the line `2` generates the following compilation error:

> Local variable i defined in an enclosing scope must be final or
>   effectively

Assigning `final` to the variable `i` results in compilation error both in line `1` and in line `2` (which is reasonable since you cannot change a final variable).

What is the reason behind the compilation error in line `2`?

This also happens in the next block of code:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void outer() {
        A[] arr = new A[10];
        for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
            arr[i] = new A() {
                private int j = i; // 1
            };
        }
    }
}
```

resulting in the same compilation error in line `1`. However, with the following changes in the code (at the marked lines `1` and `2`) I get no compilation error:

```
public class MyClass {
    public void outer() {
        A[] arr = new A[10];
        for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
            final int k = i; // 1
            arr[i] = new A() {
                private int j = k;  // 2
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get my head around the reasons behind this compilation choice, but I couldn't understand it all they way to the end. I'm guessing it has to do with possible changes the method will have on the variable but I'm not sure I understand it completely.